# spatial join on two simple features {sf} with over 1 mil. entries as fast as possible

Tags: r, join, shapefile, rgdal, r-sf

I hope this is not too trivial but I really can't find an answer and I'm too new to the topic to come up with alternatives myself. So here is the Problem:

I have two shapefiles x and y that represent different processing levels of a Sentinel2 satellite image.
x contains about 1.300.000 polygons/Segments completely covering the image extend without any further vital information.
y contains about 500 polygons representing the cloud-free area of the image (also covering most of the image except for a few "cloud-holes") as well as information about the used image in 4 columns (Sensor, Time...)

I'm trying to add the image information to x in places x is covered by y. pretty simple? I just can't find a way to make it happen without taking days.

I read x in as a simple feature {sf}, as reading it with shapefile / readOGR takes ages.
I tried different things with y

when I try merge(x,y) I can only take one sf as merge doesn't support two sf's.
merging x (as sf) and y (as shp) gives me the error "cannot allocate vector of size 13.0 Gb"

so I tried `sf::st_join(x,y)`, which supports both Variables to be sf but still didn't finish for 28 hours now

`sf::st_intersect(x,y)` took about 9 minutes for a 10.000 segment subset, so that might not be a lot faster for the whole piece.

could subsetting x to a few smaller pieces solve the whole thing or is there another simple solution? could I do something with my workspace to make the merge work or is there simply no shortcut to joining that amount of polygons?

Thanks a lot in advance and I hope my description isn't too fuzzy!

my tiny work station:
win 7 64 bit
8 GB  RAM
intel i7-4790 @ 3,6 GHz

Comment: You probably want to update the shapefile via subsetting.  Subset x where y exists and then save the desired information into x.  However, it would be easier if you showed sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I often face this kind of problems and as @manotheshark2 afirms, I prefer to work in a loop subseting my vector layer. Here is my advice:

Load your data

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
x <- readOGR('C:/', 'sentinelCovers')
y <- readOGR('C:/', 'cloudHoles')
```

Assign an y ID for identify which x polygons intersects y polygons and create the column in x table

```
x$xyID <- NA # Answer col
y$yID <- 1:nrow(y@data) # ID col
```

Run a loop subseting x

```
for (posX in 1:nrow(x@data)){
  pol.x <- x[posX, ]
  intX <- raster::intersect(pol.x, y)
  # x$xyID[posX] <- intX@data$yID ## Run this if there's unique y polygons
  # x$xyID[posX] <- paste0(intX@data$yID, collapse = ',') ## Run this if there's multiple y polygons
}
```

You can check if is better to run the loop on x o y layer

```
x$xyID <- NA # Answer col
x$xID <- 1:nrow(x@data) # ID Col

for (posY in 1:nrow(y@data)){
  pol.y <- y[posY, ]
  intY <- tryCatch(raster::intersect(pol.y, x), finally = 'NULL')
  if (is.null(intY)) next
  x$xyID[x@data$xID %in% intY@data$xID] <- pol.y$yID
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your help! running your loop on x gives me back "Error in x$xyID[pos.x] <- intX@data$yID : object 'pos.x' not found"
 on y gives me Back  "Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 10000". 

also: could the same be done using sf::st_intersect ? as reading in the segments file as sf(simple feature)  is about 6 times faster. or is the sf strukture slower on the geometrical operations intersect / join ? 
thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have a mistake in the code. Please change `pos.x` by `posX`. About the error in y layer loop maybe there's some data exceptions that I haven't considered yet. If the data isn't so heavy maybe I can check it for find the error. In which iteration the code stops? i.e. What value have `posY`? About the `sf::st_intersection()` function you are rigth. It's faster  than raster function, thanks!! For use this, x and y should be loaded using `x <- st_read('C:/sentinelCover.shp')` and replace the intersect instruction by `intX <- tryCatch(sf::st_intersection(pol.x, y), finally = 'NULL')`